# VueJS2: How to pluck out one property of an array and use it to find matching value in the second array?

Tags: vuejs2

I have two arrays. I am trying to pluck out a property from one array and use it to find the value of another property in the other way. How to do this? Let me explain:

I have an array of objects that looks like so:

`languageCodes`:

```
    {
      "code1234char3": "mdr",
      "name": "Mandar",
    },
    {
      "code1234char3": "man",
      "name": "Mandingo",
    },
   {
      // etc...
   },
```

I have another array of objects that looks like so:

`divisionLanguages`:

```
[
    {
        p_uID: 1,            
        nameLang3Char: 'mdr',
    },
    {
        p_uID: 2,
        nameLang3Char: 'man'
    },
    {
        // etc..
    }
]
```

I have a Vue template with an unordered list like so:

```
<ul v-for="x in divisionLanguages" :key="x.p_uID">
      <li>Name: FOO
      <li>Language: {{x.nameLang3Char}} - XXX</li> <--how to get 'name' value from 'languageCodes' and place here?
    </ul>
```

**Expected output should be:**

- Name: FOO
- Language: mdr - Mandar
- Name: BAR
- Language: man - Mandingo

I tried to do something like in Vue SFC template (but did not work):

```
<li>Language: {{ languageName(x.nameLanguage3Char) }}</li>
    ...
methods: {

    languageName(nameLanguage3Char) {
        const name = this.divisionLanguages.filter(x => x.code6392char3 === nameLanguage3Char)
return name.name
    }
```

I hope this makes sense of what I am trying to do.

Update: Thanks to @kellen in the comments, I change from `filte()` to `find()` like so:

```
languageName(nameLang3Char) {
  const languageName = this.languageCodes.find(
    x => x.code1234char3 == nameLang3Char
  )
  return languageName
},
```

and in  I did:
`<li>Language: {{ languageName(x.nameLang3Char).name }}</li>`

and it **works**...but I get error in console:

`Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried combining these arrays before rendering them? If you were able to combine both objects before creating that list, that would make your life easier. Another thing I noticed is you're using `filter`, when `find` might be a better option to return a single value rather than an array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: Updated question...I need to figure out correct way to delay loading until data ready, I think. Otherwise I get console error.

Comment: That's a super common issue in Vue. In your function `languageName`, it may be helpful to add the conditional `if (this.languageCodes)` before performing the `.find` query:
`
languageName(nameLang3Char) {
let languageName = ''
if (this.languageCodes) {
   languageName = this.languageCodes.find(
    x => x.code1234char3 == nameLang3Char
  )
}
  return languageName
}
`

Comment: Looks like the overall component needs to wait until another parent component is done loading data. However, I will mark you answer as solved because the `find()` suggestion is what I needed! Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help! :)